# How can I use my browser as the default mail client?

Tags: windows-7, browser, email-client

I am trying to use my browser as the default mail client for my PC.
When a different program calls the `mailto:` protocol, I want it to be passed to the browser.

I've set the default in the control panel, but it does not help.

To be clear, when I click in a mailto link on a webpage, it works fine. It's only when I click on a Send Email button from other programs that I have an issue. I get this error.

> ---------------------------
>   Email
>   ---------------------------
>   There is no email program associated to perform the requested action. Please install an email program or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Programs control panel.
>   ---------------------------
>   OK
>   ---------------------------

I went to the command prompt, and typed the path to the browser followed by "mailto:" and it opened the browser to the right page.

Comment: are you using gmail or another mail service provider (if so, specify)? Maybe also useful to specify the browser you are using...

Comment: I am using Dragon browser, but I tried it with Chrome and that didn't work either. I am using gmail, but I don't think that makes a difference as I am trying to get the browser to handle the mailto protocol.

Comment: Have you tried following procedures like these: http://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/set-gmail-as-browser-default-email-client-ht? There are also many threads on superuser.com about this issue. If you have, please specify where you're getting stuck.

Comment: I did all that and it works fine, but as I said in the post, the issue is when the mailto protocol is called from a different program.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gmail, you need to install the service handlers. this will make the browser the default for email.

Comment: I made gmail the default handler within the browser and the browser is the default mailto handler for the system. It does not work.